# iOS : How to stop a background music with only one button?

Tags: ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

I have a music button in the main UI of iOS and I want the button function as stop music button and at the same time can play the music again. My problem is I can only stop the music but can't play it again. Here is my iOS code in xcode4. How can I define one button for both play and stop music button? I have assigned one button for both stopMusic and playMusic but it doesn't work.

```
- (IBAction)stopMusic{  
    self.playBgMusic.enabled = YES;
    [self.player stop];

}

- (IBAction)playMusic{

    self.playBgMusic.enabled = YES;
    [self.player play];

}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"mp3"];
    self.player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL]; 
    player.delegate = self;
    [player play];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than have a single button try to send two different messages (`stopMusic, playMusic`), have it send `toggleMusic` every time. The `toggleMusic` method can then stop or play the music based on the current state of the player.

```
   - (IBAction)toggleMusic{  
        if ([self.player isPlaying] == YES) {
         [self.player stop];
        } else {
         [self.player play];
        }
        self.playBgMusic.enabled = YES;

    }
```

Comment: Your code is working but when i toggle it, the program quit with program received signal. Here is the line code error int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
How do i release from memory? Almost successfully. You should thank you a lot.

Comment: - (void)dealloc
{
    [player release];
    [super dealloc];
} I just added this release but doesn't work. The program quit accidentally.